# Are libphonenumber (google's and libphonenumber-js) libraries working from china?

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I know Chinese government doesn't really like google as i have had issues with implementing code for Chinese clients, at least some google APIs do not work there.

Does the libphonenumber library and/or it's lightweight version libphonenumber-js work from within China?
The question is not about them being able to parse/format Chinese numbers, but if they have their full functionality from a Chinese IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libphonenumber is just JavaScript code; it does not use network or HTTP.

It can run from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is Google's common Java, C++ and JavaScript library for parsing, formatting, and validating international phone numbers - nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, was worried there might be an http call hidden in there somewhere which could block some functionality.